# Subsetting ffdf objects in R

Tags: r, ff

I'm using R's `ff` package and I've got some `ffdf` objects (dimensions around 1.5M x 80) that I need to work with.  I'm having some trouble getting my head around the efficient slicing/dicing operations though.

For instance I've got two integer columns named "YEAR" and "AGE", and I want to make a table of AGE when the YEAR is 2005.

One approach is this:

```
ffwhich <- function(x, expr) {
  b <- bit(nrow(x))
  for(i in chunk(x)) b[i] <- eval(substitute(expr), x[i,])
  b
}
bw <- ffwhich(a.fdf, YEAR==1999)
answer <- table(a.fdf[bw, "AGE"])
```

The `table()` operation is fast but building the bit vector is quite slow.  Anyone have any recommendations for doing this better?

Answer (score 1):

The package `ffbase` provides many base functions for `ff`/`ffdf` objects, including `subset.ff`.  With a bit of limited testing, it seems that `subset.ff` is relatively fast.  Try loading `ffbase` and then using the simpler code you suggested from a previous comment (`with(subset(a.fdf, YEAR==1999)`).

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with manipulating `ff` objects, but the problem you describe sounds like a classic `tapply()` task:

```
answer <- tapply(a.fdf$YEAR[a.fdf$YEAR == 1995], a.fdf$AGE[a.fdf$YEAR == 1995], length)
```

I would assume something like that would move faster than the two-step solution you give above, but maybe I'm misunderstanding how `ff` data structures work?

Comment: If it weren't `ff`, I could do something much simpler, like `with(subset(a.fdf, YEAR==1999), table(AGE))`.  `ff` is the part that makes it trickier.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be something like this:

```
system.time({ 
 index <- as.ff( which( a.fdf[,'Location'] == 'exonic') ); 
 table(a.fdf[index,][,'Function']);
});                                                                                             
user  system elapsed 
1.128   0.172   1.317
```

Seems to be significantly faster than:

```
system.time({
 bw <- ffwhich(a.fdf, Location=="exonic");  
 table(a.fdf[bw,'Function']);
})
user  system elapsed 
24.901   0.208  25.150
```

YMMV, as these are factors, not characters, and my ffdf is ~4.3M * 42.

```
identical(table(a.fdf[bw,'Function']), table(a.fdf[index,][,'Function']));
[1] TRUE
```